# asp.net: which data collection should be used to return a table

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, data-collection

I'm using a stored procedure to create a temporary table and want to return it in a data collection:

```
public static >>data collection<< reportData(int intUserID)    
{
SqlConnection con = Sql.getConnection();

                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Get_Results", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", intUserID);
                    con.Open();
                    //put into data collection
                    //return data collection
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Log Error
                    con.Close();
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
}
```

I don't know which data collection is best though to return. I might need to do some processing on it though so I'm not sure what would be best, performance is not a major concern. I was thinking of a DataSet or DataReader but didn't know if there is anything better suited, or best practise. Any help is much appreciated

using .NET 2.0, vstudio 2005.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) is a common choice and works well for most things.

You can bind this guy to a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) and get a lot of functionality right off the cuff.

- Sorting
- Custom styling
- Paging